# Open local HTML files in compatibility view (IE7) in IE11/WIN7

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

Friend of mine has an interesting issue on his new corporate PC - it looks like his IE11 is somehow configured to open all HTML files from the local file system in compatibility mode (IE7).

While I'm aware of the Compatibility View for the specific web-sites and UNC paths, compatibility meta tag and "saved from" comment, it looks like all of these options are not applied here. The computer's options are hidden so I cannot examine them.

I've Googled for a solution but the most relevant result was to use the "display all sites in compatibility mode" option in IE8 (which is not applicable to IE11).

I can see two alternatives:

- Somehow the filter for all the local files is added to the Compatibility View settings (I've tried it on my machine, but it just does not allow the file://* pattern)
- Somehow the local files are marked as intranet and the compatibility view is turned on for all intranet websites. There is a filter for that which allows file:\server\share patterns but it looks like it does not allow the pattern file://* as well.

Do you know how to configure IE7 mode to be the default one in IE11?

This very simple file demonstrates the issue:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="test.png">';
  alert(document.body.innerHTML);
};
</script>
<body></body>
```

If the page is in the IE7 mode, the IMG path will be absolute in the message box.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hack that allows you to run in compatibility mode with local files in IE11.   You just need to use the invisible share associated with your Drive.. so for instance, in Windows Explorer, instead of opening C:\folder\whatever.html,
open \\COMPUTERNAME\C$\folder\whatever.html in IE.   Then it will treat the file whatever.html as an Intranet file (instead of an "Internet" file).