# Add local file to IE11 Trusted Zone or Local Intranet

Tags: internet-explorer

I'd like to add a local file `(C:\Users\David\AppData\LocalLow\LastPass\iehome2.html)` `LastPass` needs to open my `LastPassVault` in `IE11`.

Scripting is disabled in my Internet zone and the file needs JavaScript in order to work (`"JavaScript is required for this page to function."`).

However, I am having a hard time adding the file to IE's Trusted Sites or Local Intranet.

The most logical thing to me is to add `file://*` to the zones, but IE won't except that [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcRxH.jpg)

Comment: There's a possible solution here: http://superuser.com/questions/149068/how-to-add-a-local-file-to-trusted-zone-in-ie8

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work

Comment: The answer is so simple, it's disgusting: Thank you, StackExchange superser Eric! Click here:
[Get Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) to allow local files into Compatibility View permanently using UNC Network Path.](http://superuser.com/a/896806/620566)