# Always open local XML in compatibility mode in IE11

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-11, unc, xslt

I have an XML-File, which references a DTD, which references an XSL.

When I open it with the Internet Explorer 11, it gets displayed as a normal XML without any stylesheets would.

I managed to open it in compatibility mode using the solution given in this thread
[Open local HTML files in compatibility view (IE7) in IE11/WIN7](https://superuser.com/questions/874675/open-local-html-files-in-compatibility-view-ie7-in-ie11-win7) and the XML was displayed with the correct XSL styles.

However, always changing the path in the URL is not something I want to do.

Is there a way to force IE11 to always open a local file in compatibility mode?

Or if that doesn't work is there a way to force IE11 to always use the UNC-Path?

Comment: Add the first 2 lines from your XML.